# Swashbuckle.AspNetCore 5.X.x or 6.x.x Failed when trying to install in my .net 5 project

Tags: c#, .net-core, nuget

I got warnings below when tried to add Swashbuckle.AspNetCore in my project. Could someone help me with this issue please, newbie here. Thanks, I also got the latest Visual Studio installed:

Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019

Version 16.11.3

**Warning:**

NU3012: Package 'Microsoft.OpenApi 1.2.3' from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json': The author primary signature found a chain building issue: NotValidForUsage: The certificate is not valid for the requested usage.

NU3012: Package 'Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger 6.2.1' from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json': The repository primary signature found a chain building issue: NotValidForUsage: The certificate is not valid for the requested usage.

NU3012: Package 'Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen 6.2.1' from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json': The repository primary signature found a chain building issue: NotValidForUsage: The certificate is not valid for the requested usage.

NU3012: Package 'Swashbuckle.AspNetCore 6.2.1' from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json': The repository primary signature found a chain building issue: NotValidForUsage: The certificate is not valid for the requested usage.

NU3012: Package 'Microsoft.Extensions.ApiDescription.Server 3.0.0' from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json': The author primary signature found a chain building issue: NotValidForUsage: The certificate is not valid for the requested usage.

NU3012: Package 'Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI 6.2.1' from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json': The repository primary signature found a chain building issue: NotValidForUsage: The certificate is not valid for the requested usage.

Sample Image when creating my simple project:

[image]

Comment: Do you use docker in your project?

Comment: @OliverDzaeck, I've added the image of my simple Web Api project. I believe docker is not use, it was just a simple web API.

Comment: It might be a transient issue with nuget. Does the issue still exist?

Comment: @abdusco, just tried to create a fresh web api project using .net 5, and yes I still can't add Swashbuckle.AspNetCore. I also tried to install in the NuGet package manager but still failed :(

Comment: Also running into the same issue on .Net 6.